# How to organise react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have 3 components and all 3 components have an input field, I read that is better to create a separate component where code repeats. So, in this case I can create a component InputField.js

```
const InputField = ({ val, setVal }) => {
    return (
        <input 
            value={val}
            onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
            className='border block'
        />
    )
}

export default InputField
```

I wasn't sure where to have the state for this component and I decided to pass it from components that will use this InputField component.

I guess is no other option, right ? Because If I declare here

```
const [val,setVal] = useState(0)
```

Then other components where I will use it will not know about this state, because state is private and only this component know about it ?

Then I have this other 2 components that uses this InputField component, the third one I haven't created yet.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { HiOutlineSwitchHorizontal } from 'react-icons/hi'
import InputField from './InputField'


const MilesKm = ({ title}) => {
    const [isSwitchClicked, setIsSwitchClicked] = useState(false)
    const [val, setVal] = useState(0)
    let result = 0

    if(isSwitchClicked){
        result = val / 1.60934
    } else {
        result = val * 1.60934
    }

    return (
        <section className='p-10'>
            <h1 className='mt-6 text-xl'>{title}</h1>
            <div className='flex w-2/3 gap-4 items-center justify-start mt-4'>
                <span>{isSwitchClicked ? 'Kilometers' : 'Miles'}</span> 
                   <HiOutlineSwitchHorizontal 
                        onClick={() => setIsSwitchClicked(!isSwitchClicked)}
                    />
                <span className=''>{isSwitchClicked ? 'Miles': 'Kilometers'}</span>
            </div>
            <InputField val={val} setVal={setVal} />
         
            <p>{isSwitchClicked ? `Kilometers to Miles = ${result.toFixed(2)}` : (`Miles to Kilometers =  ${result.toFixed(2)}`)}</p>
        </section>
    )
}

export default MilesKm
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import InputField from './InputField'


const Bmi = ({ title }) => {
    const [val, setVal] = useState({
      cm: 0,
      kg: 0
    })

//to avoid global variable result:
const calculateBMI = () => {
    console.log(typeof(val));
    return (val.kg / (val.cm * 0.01)).toFixed(2)
}
    
    return (
        <section className='p-10'>
        <h1 className='mt-6 text-xl'>{title}</h1>
        <div className='flex-col mt-4'>
            <label>Enter height in cm</label>
            <InputField val={val.cm} setVal={(preVal) => setVal({...val, cm: preVal})}/>
            <label>Enter kilograms</label>
            <InputField val={val.kg} setVal={(prevVal) => setVal({...val, kg: prevVal})}/>
            {/* <label>Enter age</label>
            <InputField val={val.kg}/> */}
        </div>
    
        <p>{val  && `Your BMI = ${calculateBMI()}`}</p>
        </section>
    )
}

export default Bmi
```

Here I kinda got confused, and I wondered if is normal to do such thing in react js ?
Because In InputField component has variable val and function setter setVal, and I console loged it and says type string.

Then in MilesKm.js component state values are passed to InputField component and because I needed those values to make calculations with them I thought should be number and I initialised val with 0.

Then in Bmi.js I realised I need height and kg and I thought why not make it an object ?

then in bmi.js Nan happened and I got so confused and I console loged type of val in each component and I saw in InputField is type string, in MilesKm is type number and in Bmi is type object.

My thoughts are:
How professionals organise the components ? What they consider when organising components ? Is good practice the way I did the components above ? I do need input in different components, and apparently with different types for values.
It's just something that I think about but I have no one to ask except google, but I haven't found answers just typescript.

Comment: I had to do such a thing in one of my recent project, so I don't think it's abnormal to do it.
However, if you can, I recommend you to use a library to manage your forms, you will save a lot of time. (You can take a look at formik for example)

Comment: What type of project ? Work, school or personal project ? Thanks

Comment: Work project, it worked, but not the easiest code to maintain to be honest. (that's why I don't recommend you to do it by yourself)

If your form is not dynamic, you could also take a look at uncontrolled input, letting you retrieve all the values of your form when you want to submit it.

Answer (score -1):

For your Input component I would split it into a TextInput and a NumericInput. For the NumericInput I would add this to the onChange:
onChange={e => {
const regExString = `^-?\\d{0,${numberOfWholeDigitsToUse}}(\\.\\d{0,${numberOfDecimalsToUse}})?$`;
const valueRegEx = new RegExp(regExString);
if (e.target.value.length === 0 || valueRegEx.test(e.target.value)) {
setText?.(e.target.value);
onChange?.(e.target.value);
}
}}
Then put this into a common components folder like so: [image]

Comment: Is an interesting approach to have separate components for input for each type of values passed to them.